Convergence in Measure for a Sequence of Measurable Functions
Question:
I'm working through a problem in Real Analysis using definitions from "Real Analysis" by Royden and Fitzpatrick and need help proving convergence in measure for a sequence of measurable functions. The problem is stated as follows:
Let $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a sequence of positive real numbers converging to zero, and let $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a sequence of measurable functions on $ E $.
Define
$$
E_n = \{ x \in E : |f_n(x)| \geq a_n \}.
$$
Prove that if $ \lim_{n \to \infty} m(E_n) = 0 $, then $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ converges to $ 0 $ in measure.
Relevant Definition:
From the book, a sequence of measurable functions $ \{f_n\} $ converges to a function $ f$ in measure on a set $ E $ if, for every $ \eta > 0 $,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{x \in E : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \eta\}) = 0.
$$
In this case, we want to show convergence to zero, meaning:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{x \in E : |f_n(x)| > \eta\}) = 0
$$
for all $ \eta > 0 $.
What I understand:
The sets $ E_n $ represent where the functions $ f_n $ exceed the threshold $ a_n $, and since $ a_n \to 0 $, it seems reasonable that these sets should shrink in measure. Given that $ m(E_n) \to 0 $, I believe this should imply that $ f_n \to 0 $ in measure.
However, I am struggling to rigorously connect this with the formal definition of convergence in measure. Could someone provide a step-by-step outline or detailed proof for how to show that $ f_n \to 0 $ in measure using this definition?
What I've tried:
I understand that as $ n \to \infty $, the measure of the sets $ E_n $ where $ |f_n(x)| \geq a_n $ goes to zero, but I am unsure how to extend this result to show convergence in measure. Any hints or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

If $\epsilon >0$ then ${x\in E:|f_n(x)|>\epsilon}\subseteq  E_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

For a fixed $\eta > 0$ we know that for sufficiently large $n$, $0 < a_n < \eta$.
Therefore, for these $n$, we know that $$E_n = \{x \in E : |f_n(x)| \geq a_n \} \supseteq \{x \in E : |f_n(x)| \geq \eta\}$$
so
$$m(E_n) \geq m(\{x \in E : |f_n(x)| \geq \eta \}) \geq 0$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. So taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, the Squeeze Theorem shows $$\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{x \in E : |f_n(x)| \geq \eta \}) = 0$$
as desired.
